# How do I put data from a pdf into the table of two columns by checking for bold text>

Tags: python, excel, pdf

I am currently trying to analyze a book to create a database without manually entering the information into excel. The program will run, yet it will not return and save the data in the table like I request. Everytime I open the excel file, it is completely empty. I am trying to fetch the data using bold lettering from the pdf and then retreiving the information after it, then resetting it after it has been input

Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextContainer

# Function to check if text appears to be bold based on style attributes
 def is_bold_text(text):
    return "bold" in text.lower()

# PDF file path
pdf_path = '\content\JAVAREFERENCE.pdf'

data = []
current_bold_text = ''
current_content = ''

# Extract text and layout using pdfminer
text = extract_text(pdf_path, laparams=LAParams())

for obj in text:
    if isinstance(obj, LTTextContainer):
        text = obj.get_text()

        # Check if the text appears to be bold based on style attributes
        is_bold = is_bold_text(text)

        if is_bold:
             # Append the previous bold text if exists before starting a new bold section
             if current_bold_text:
                 data.append((current_bold_text, current_content))
                 current_content = ''  # Reset the content
                 current_bold_text = text
        else:
            current_content += text + ' '

# Append the last section
if current_bold_text:
    data.append((current_bold_text, current_content))

# Create an Excel workbook and worksheet
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

# Write the data to Excel
for row, (bold_text, content) in enumerate(data, start=1):
    worksheet.cell(row=row, column=1, value=bold_text)
    worksheet.cell(row=row, column=2, value=content)

# Save the Excel file
workbook.save('output6.xlsx')
```

Any help with this subject would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I have tried a few things, involving pandas, and PDFReader, but none have worked. Please help